# timing function for while loop

Tags: ros, sleep, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was just wondering, if I want to write a while loop which says while x seconds hasn't reach execute this statement, how would I go about it?
I tried using
while(ros::Duration(x).sleep()){
....
}
but it doesn't work. also, tried creating a counter but there is no way to measure the count in seconds

thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42476/timing-function-for-while-loop/) by [Arash](https://answers.ros.org/users/3093/arash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Example code that should do what you want:

```
ros::Time start_time = ros::Time::now();
ros::Duration timeout(2.0); // Timeout of 2 seconds
while(ros::Time::now() - start_time < timeout) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on 2021-11-06**:
it's not working for me if I give 2 for a timeout the loops do not stop for milliseconds. I tried giving 100 and the same result. but when I gave 200 it remains for some time.  but I cannot find the relationship